# Slack API file uploads: permissions and ownership

Tags: file-upload, slack-api, slack

I am using the Slack API to upload files. https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

If you include a channel when you upload a file to it becomes accessible to everyone in that channel, otherwise it is only available to the person who created the API key. Also, when a file is posted to a channel it displays as the user who created the API key.

### Questions

1. Is a way to share with everyone on a team without posting the file in a public channel?
2. Is there a way to upload a file as another user or as a bot?

I tried `files.sharedPublicURL`, but these links allow anyone to view files. I want to make file accessible only to a slack team.

There is an option when on the channel info pane when you click "View all file in #channel" to "Include files from integrations & bots". This seems to indicate that it is possible to upload files as a bot.

[image: Include files from integrations & bots]

Answer (score 2):

1. Sure, by choosing in which channels you share the file, you can control who can see it. That also works with private channels.
2. No, a file must always belong to a user, a bot  would not be sufficient. Also the file is always owned by the user linked to the access token used. If you want to rather use a generic user, A workaround is to create a generic user fort you Slack that is only used for bot-related tasks. (Mine is called slackadmin)

Comment: That is kind of was expecting for both questions. Creating a slack account for the API seems like the best route. Thanks.

Comment: I used the technique you described in your answer, but I noticed an option in the slack app UI to show files from bots which made me wonder if it is possible to user a bot to upload images.  I added a screenshot in the question.

Comment: I stand corrected. Apparently you can use a bot user to upload files. Not sure if that is a recent change, but according to the documentation it should indeed work.

Comment: The answer for nr 1 isn't exactly useful. The question was whether it was possible to share the file (read, allow people to download the file) without having to create a message for it.
Currently, if you use a bot to upload a file, without specifying channels, that file will belong to the bot and can't be downloaded by anyone except for the bot. If you add channels, it will actually post a message, which might be something you don't want.